# MVC3 Bootstrap tablular data with a grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, grid

I love Bootstrap, and I love MVC 3 and MVC 4, however even though I see plenty of Bootstrap examples I'm not really seeing example on using Bootstrap with MVC3 with tabular data in a grid like system.

Any examples anywhere?

1. I do not want to use Telerik, KendoUI, or many of these other things
2. Really not thrilled with the "WebGrid" as I would prefer to stay away from tables

So any solid thoughts on Bootstrap with Razor View Engine, and how about avoiding the use of tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think about this a bit different. All twitter bootstrap gives you is just a bunch of styles.

```
1.  <table class="table table-bordered">
2.    …
3.  </table>
```

If you are using ASP.NET MVC Razor, Angular.JS, Knockout.js, Handbar.js or anything that allows you to take data and programmatically create dynamic html you will have to setup according to the syntax of the language.

```
@Model List<string>

<table class="table table-bordered">
      @foreach(var item in @Model){
        <tr>
          <td>@item</td>
       </tr>
      }
</table>
```

Bootstrap only provides you a common library of reusable styles. Some of the HTML has to be layout in a certain way to get the styles to behave correctly but this is by design and one should refer to the documentation @ http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html for more help.